# App Store Connect Mixing Screenshots and Previews

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

We are on the verge of uploading our first production app to the App Store. I have taken screenshots using an iPhone 8 (4.7"), an iPhone X (5.8"), and an iPad (9.7").

Now, I understand based on Apple's documentation that it is valid to upload these "alternative sizes" (aside: these alternative sizes are ~70% of iOS devices but I digress) and the sizes will be upscaled accordingly to the larger sizes of iPhone (5.5") and iPhone X (6.5", XS Max only as of this writing), and iPad Pro (10.5", 11", 12.9").

My issue is that the promo video for my app was produced at the conventional HD 1080x1920 (valid for 5.5") and 1200x1600 (valid for 12.9"). I can of course downscale these, but ideally I would like to keep the original higher resolution. So my question is: if I upload a mixed bag of assets, will e.g. an iPad Pro still display my preview video AND the upscaled smaller images from my 9.7" upload? Will an iPhone X, which has its own images but a promo uploaded only for 5.5" still show that iPhone 5.5" promo? In most general terms, can I mix and match sizes and expect the App Store to provide assets to the user appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with Apple. The short of it is that App Previews (video) and App Screenshots (stills) are separate entities, so you can mix and match. That said, according to the rep with whom I spoke they will never upscale images or video for you. So you should always use the largest device size. He suggested that any images I had in a lower scale I scale up in Photoshop and then submit.